# Show table only after doing a search

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on this little project and I wanted the table with the results only to show up after I hit the button / make a search...

Here is the link http://img.needforgaming.x10.mx/procurar.php
My goal is to hide the table before making a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to check if the form was submitted.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_procurar'])){

//display form

}
```

An alternative would be to use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

//display form    

}
```

Hope this helps!